# Primefaces DataExport throws: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString

Tags: java, primefaces, apache-poi, data-export

My WebApp throws an Exception and I have no clue why. The error occurs when I am pushing a primefaces dataexporter-button.

I am using **NetBeans 7.4, Mojarra 2.1.27, PrimeFaces 3.5**

I also included apache poi-3.9 (also tried 3.7) which contains the RichTextString.class, so why does the Application not find it at runtime? Any ideas?

If there some information missing, please let me know.

---

Stacktrace:

> WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>       at org.primefaces.component.export.ExporterFactory.getExporterForType(ExporterFactory.java:30)
>       at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:87)
>       at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
>       at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1093)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>       at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

---

project.xml

> 

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<project xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/project/1">

<type>org.netbeans.modules.web.project</type>


-<configuration>


-<data xmlns="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/web-project/3">

<name>RDBS</name>

<minimum-ant-version>1.6.5</minimum-ant-version>


-<web-module-libraries>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-fileupload-1.3.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-io-2.4.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jaxen-1.1.6.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.poi-ooxml-3.9.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.primefaces-extensions-0.7.0-20130409.040543-51.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.xdb6.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.xmlparserv2.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.dynamicreports-adhoc-3.1.4.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.dynamicreports-core-3.1.4.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.avalon-framework-impl-4.2.0.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.barbecue-1.5-beta1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.barcode4j-2.0.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-anim-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-awt-util-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-bridge-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-css-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-dom-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-ext-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-gvt-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-parser-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-script-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-svg-dom-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-util-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.batik-xml-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.bcprov-jdk14-138.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-collections-3.2.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-digester-2.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-lang-2.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-lang3-3.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.commons-logging-1.1.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.itext-2.1.7.js2.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jackson-annotations-2.0.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jackson-core-2.0.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jackson-databind-2.0.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jasperreports-5.0.4.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jcommon-1.0.15.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jdtcore-3.1.0.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jfreechart-1.0.12.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.json-20080701.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.jxl-2.6.10.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.log4j-1.2.14.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.serializer-2.7.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.spring-beans-2.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.spring-core-2.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.velocity-1.7.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.xalan-2.7.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.xml-apis-1.3.04.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.xml-apis-ext-1.3.04.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.xbean.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.dom4j-1.6.1.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.primefaces-3.5.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>


-<library dirs="200">

<file>${file.reference.poi-3.9.jar}</file>

<path-in-war>WEB-INF/lib</path-in-war>

</library>

</web-module-libraries>

<web-module-additional-libraries/>


-<source-roots>

<root id="src.dir"/>

</source-roots>


-<test-roots>

<root id="test.src.dir"/>

</test-roots>

</data>

</configuration>

</project>
```

Comment: In case you are using maven, could you show us your pom.xml?

Comment: I do not know much about any build-tools, I am just using the "build project"-functionality of netbeans. But maybe the "project.xml" is helpful? I will add this to my question.

Comment: Could you check in your application server if the deployed war has the lib poi 3.9 in it (WEB-INF/lib)? Just to eliminate the possibility that the jar is not being packaged with you war application due to some build problem.

Comment: @DanielCamargo Yes, the war-file contains all libs. (located in WEB-INF/lib)

Comment: A few days ago i tried to set up some libs as glassfish-server-libs and I did not remove the primeface lib from the server properly. This seems to result in some strange conflicts. removing this redundant lib solved my problem.. Thanks @DanielCamargo for your time and help

Comment: I'm glad you made it!